# Can you pass a variable to a data member in Python as done in Pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

Here is the sample code from the `nn.Module` of pytorch documentation:

```
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 20, 5)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(20, 20, 5)

    def forward(self, x):
       x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
       return F.relu(self.conv2(x))
```

Here, we are passing `x` to `self.conv1()` in the `forward` function.
However, `self.conv1` is a variable as can been from this line `self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 20, 5)` in the `__init__` function.

How is this possible?

Comment: A variable can refer to a function (or other callable object) just as easily as any other type of data.

Comment: Are you saying `self.conv1` is referring to a function? I thought we were storing `nn.Conv2d(1, 20, 5)` - the model that was created for our neural network in `self.conv1`. Should we not be passing the model and the data to a separate function, instead of passing the data to `self.conv1`.

Comment: It's a callable object of some sort - I'm not familiar with PyTorch, so I'm not sure exactly what it is, but I suspect it's an instance of a Pytorch class that has a `__call__()` method defined, so it can be called just like a function.

Answer (score 1):

Forward passes of anything in pytorch, layer or network, is done in functional way `var(x)`. This is made in python with overwriting `__call__()` built-in. Try it yourself. Make a class, overwrite `__call__()` and use it like function.

Answer (score 0):

I see this is a nice question.

```
self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 20, 5)
```

`self.conv1` is indeed a variable, but it is also the as special class variable derived `nn.Module` (read: module).

And it is also a callable, implemented `__call__` method and this is why we can call it.

Comment: I think I get it now. The `__call__` method is defined for the class `nn.Conv2d`. As `self.conv1` is an instance of this class, due to this line: `self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 20, 5)`. We are able to call the instance of `nn.Conv2d`, which happens to be `self.conv1`.